# How to Include third party github repo in my project

Tags: git, github, version-control, continuous-deployment

I want to include a github repo in my project. In the command during the build I am install the git repo in my project using pip But I want to do it through sha1sum and update it periodically as we want new features, so that if third party project breaks their master branch temporarily it doesn't break our project build. Can we achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this sounds exactly like the `git submodules` use case. Read its man-page for more information.